# Restrict angle of swipe to scroll UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have a vertical scroll view that needs to be scrollable but I want to use the left and right swipe gestures for something else. I have the behavior for each swipe direction working, but I want to restrict the angle of a swipe that scrolls the UIScrollView, so that it has to be really, really vertical, and most left or right leaning swipes activate the other behavior and do not change the scroll position.

I know that I can get the swipe angle by overriding `scrollViewDidScroll` and comparing the previous and current `contentOffset`, but I cannot stop the scrollview from scrolling there.

How can I limit the angle of a swipe that scrolls a UIScrollView ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think **scrollViewDidScroll** is too late for what you want to achieve.

Maybe try setting the **directionalLockEnabled** property of the **UIScrollView** to **YES**.*(not sure if this helps... but play with it)*

And/Or implement the **UIScrollViewDelegate** method `- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView` and within this methods implementation grab a pointer to the **panGestureRecognizer** *(readonly)* property of the **UIScrollView** passed in.

From there call **translationInView:** on the **UIPanGestureRecognizer**, passing in the view in whose coordinate system the translation of the pan gesture should be computed, and with the **CGPoint** returned use trigonometry to calculate the angle and if it's not within predetermined limits call **setTranslationInView:** on the **UIPanGestureRecognizer** to restore.